# Globals and when they need to be declared

Tags: python, scope, global

In the following code:

```
>>> import time
>>> cache = {}
>>> 
>>> def squared(num):
...     if num in cache: return cache[num]
...     print ("Calculating...")
...     time.sleep(1) # fake a calculation
...     result = num * num
...     cache[num] = result
...     return result
... 
>>> squared(2)
Calculating...
4
>>> squared(2)
4
>>> cache
{2: 4}
```

Why is it that I can modify the `cache` from within the function and don't have to call `global` in the function? Is `global` directly related to whether a variable is mutable/immutable, or why does it work in the above case?

Comment: Here's a hint: if you replace `cache[num] = result` with `cache = {num: result}`, you'll get an [UnboundLocalError](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value).

Comment: global had **nothing** to do with mutability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function sees the outside cache variable.
Because it is mutable it can mutate it and it can be seen inside the function as well as outside the function.

You will need to use global if you want to assign a new value to a name and want also the outer name to be bound to this value.
For example if you want to assign 3 to the name “cache” you use cache =3. If you don’t declare it as global it would be a simple local variable inside the function and the outer cache name will still be bound to its original value.

Comment: ok so basically if the object is immutable you need to use the `global` keyword to change it in the global scope, correct? If it's mutable you can just change it anywhere and not worry about it.

Comment: @Kyle *no* you can **never** change an immutable object. That is what immutable means

Comment: @kyle, I think you are coupling two separate and independent issues. mutable/immutable and name scopes. The former talks about the ability to change an Object (value), the latter is in what scope to change the binding of a some variable name (not value).